# any way to run "git pull" in every one minute

Tags: node.js, git

I am using [supervisor](https://github.com/laughinghan/node-supervisor) to start node server. There is options in "supervisor --help" called

> -p|--poll-interval 
>       How often to poll watched files for changes.
>       Defaults to Node default.

But it is not what I want. I'd like to run "git pull" in shell in every 1 minute. Is there anyway to do it?
It could be in NPM or supervisor, or something else.

Comment: *Is there anyway to do it?* Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use cron job in linux/unix, and task scheduler for windows. And they're similar.

For cron job, first write a shell script to do what you want, like `git pull` something. Suppose it's `/scripts/git_pull_job.sh`, and make it executable.

```
chmod 755 /scripts/git_pull_job.sh
```

Then add the job. In the terminal input:

```
crontab -e
```

Then in the `VI` style editor, input things like below, and save and close as `VI`. It will run every minute.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

* * * * * /scripts/git_pull_job.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just run a cron job?  git is not a node functionality, it's an OS functionality.  Use an OS tool.

Comment: I heard about cron job, but never use it before. Is it possible you can provide some demo code for this task?